# How to programmatically submit a password to a stand alone program in C#

Tags: c#

I am making a C# application (using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, using WinForms) that needs to open a password protected .docx file in C#. I know you can do:

```
Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE", "filename.docx");
```

To start word (I'm using Microsoft Word 2016) with that file loaded in. But I also want to submit the password to Word so it opens without me doing anything. I know it's not this simple, but this is what imagining right now:

```
public void submitPassword(string password)
{
    Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE", "filename.docx" //something like this: System.Password.Sumbit("WINWORD.EXE", password));
}
```

Comment: A quick search for Word Command Line Switches [suggests](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/list-of-microsoft-word-2010-command-line-startup-switches) there isn't a command line switch for password

Comment: @MattBurland but I'm using C#, not command line. Does C# use command line for Processes?

Comment: @JacobGarner Yes, Process is just a programmatic way of using the command line.

Comment: @Casey so is there a way to do this without Process?

Comment: @JacobGarner In the worst case maybe you can manipulate the mouse and keyboard as a separate step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided to me by Andrew Piliser got me close, but not there. This is what works:

```
   using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
   ...
   public void submitPassword()
   {
        var wordApp = new Word.Application();
        wordApp.Visible = true;
        wordApp.Documents.Open(FileName: @"filepath", PasswordDocument: "filepassword");
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a COM type library called `Microsoft Word Object Library`. In Visual Studio, you can add a reference to it from the solution explorer. Right click References, click Add Reference, go to the COM tab, and search for Word.

With the package `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`, you can create an `Application` instance and tell it to open a document using a password.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

...

public void SubmitPassword(string password)
{
    Application app = new Application();
    app.Documents.Open(FileName: @"filepath", PasswordDocument: password);
}
```

Comment: This almost works. But I get a message that says that I (Jacob) have it locked for editing. Did I do something wrong with this?

Comment: I tried it again. It works, but word does not start. What's going on?

Comment: I'm getting the lock message too, I'm not sure why. You can try looking into the documentation for [the package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.aspx), or try searching for Word OLE automation.

Comment: after messing around and doing some web searching I found out how it works. See my answer.